# How to create toggle sidebar for desktop view in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I want a toggle sidebar in my ionic 4 app for desktop and other large devices. I am attaching a screenshot of what I exactly want. Please help[image]

Answer (score 0):

while creating project use **ionic projectname sidemenu** this command you will get the side-menu.

Comment: And if you want that icon, you can refer ionic icons from here.
https://ionicons.com/

Comment: I have sidebar but toggle is not working on desktop. I want sidebar like https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/desktop-app this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a side menu template using this commend:

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

There are two types of menu overlay(default in android) and push. In your link is push menu, add like this:

```
<ion-menu type="push">
::
::
</ion-menu>
```

check out for more here [ionic side menu](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu)